# Congruence - Proofs

Tags: prime-numbers, congruences

I'm stuck on this question. I tried, but don't know how to proceed:

> Given that $p$ and $q$ are primes, prove that $p + q = (p − q)^3$ if and only if $p = 5$ and $q = 3$.

Is there a way to solve this equation through a congruence relation?

I start by setting:

> $(p − q)^3 \equiv 0 \ \mod \ p + q$

Comment: Just started solving through congruence. It confuses me sometimes.
Anyway, I tried solving through (modulo p+q). I couldn't progress.

Comment: @mowais21 It's not at all clear to me what that means. Why don't you edit the OP to show your work?

Comment: I don't understand the question as well. Asked my instructor for a hint. He just told me to try solving through (modulo p+q). I know that I should do it through congruence, but can't figure it out.

Comment: @mowais21 I mean that I don't understand your explanation of what you tried. I understand the question perfectly well.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I'm sorry. I meant starting by the following congruence relation:
(p-q)^3 = 0 (mod p+q)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ p\!-\!q\mid p\!+\!q\,\Rightarrow\, p\!-\!q\mid 2p,2q\,\Rightarrow\, p\!-\!q\mid (2p,2q) = 2(p,q) = 2$

Comment: That's a good hint! I was going off in the wrong direction on this one.

Answer (score 1):

$$(p+q)=(p-q)^3$$
let suppose that $p=q=2$. then we have:
$$4=(0)^3-0$$ which is impossible.

Let suppose wlog that $p=2$ and $q$ is odd. Then $p-2$ and $p+2$ are co-prime therefore $$(p+2)\neq (p-2)^3$$

Let $p$ and $q$ be 2 odd primes.
Since $p$ and $q$ are prime then their sum and difference are even.
we set $$p+q=2r$$
$$p-q=2s$$
It follows that
$$p=(r+s)$$
$$q=r-s$$
Futhermore
$$2r=8s^3$$
$$r=4s^3$$
Since $\gcd(p,q)=1$ then $s=1$
Hence
$$r=4$$
It follows
$$p=4+1=5$$
$$q=4-1=3$$

Comment: How can you suppose that the sum and difference of p and q is even. Suppose either of p or q is 2, then the sum/difference may be odd.

Comment: Thanks I edited the answer. I forgot the only even prime.